# Intercambio entre formato de colores en java

Tags: java, color, bufferedimage, rgba

En un programa estoy extrayendo el color de un bit determinado de una imagen con el metodo:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

BufferedImage image = null;

image = ImageIO.read(new File(dir));

for(int i=0;i<800;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<800;j++){
        int biomeColour = image.getRGB(i, j);
```

El problema esta en que el image.getRGB() me devuelve el color en el formato 8-bit RGBA segun la api de java: [Página de la api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB). Como se haria para cambiar de este formato al formato de RGB

Comment: He encontrado una forma de hacerlo, para quien le interese:`import java.awt.image.DirectColorModel;

DirectColorModel = tranformMatrix = new DirectColorModel(32, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff);

float red = tranformMatrix.getRed(biomeColour);
float green = tranformMatrix.getGreen(biomeColour);
float blue = tranformMatrix.getBlue(biomeColour);`

Comment: Puedes poner tu solución como una auto-respuesta, de hecho es algo que también es beneficioso para esta comunidad y podrías ganar dobles puntos si alguien busca solución al mismo problema

Comment: @RusianLópezCarro Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado una forma de hacerlo, para quien le interese:

```
import java.awt.image.DirectColorModel; 

DirectColorModel = tranformMatrix = new DirectColorModel(32, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff); 

float red = tranformMatrix.getRed(biomeColour); 
float green = tranformMatrix.getGreen(biomeColour); 
float blue = tranformMatrix.getBlue(biomeColour);
```